Android Godot integration: limit log
I was able to connect native Android with a 3D Godot fragment. But the "problem" I am having is that Godot just spews out this log that completely blocks me from seeing anything else that I log. Here's an excerpt
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 192 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0x727fdde06890 hos timage handle 0x7000200000ba4 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 186 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0x727fdde05b50 hos timage handle 0x7000200000ba2 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 187 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0x727fdde05910 hos timage handle 0x7000200000ba3 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 183 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0x727fdde06890 hos timage handle 0x7000200000ba4 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 191 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0x727fdde05b50 hos timage handle 0x7000200000ba2 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 189 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0x727fdde05910 hos timage handle 0x7000200000ba3 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 188 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0x727fdde06890 hos timage handle 0x7000200000ba4 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 190 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0x727fdde05b50 hos timage handle 0x7000200000ba2 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 185 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0x727fdde05910 hos timage handle 0x7000200000ba3 
I/MESA    ( 6510): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 192

It basically logs the same line for every frame, so i get this tens of times per second. Can I somehow configure the logging to disable this?

I don't know if this is going to help you.
In the Filter text field (next to magnifying glass) add this:
!I/MESA
Here are some images as proof of concept:
Before:
After: 

Same issue as in: Excessive Logging After Flutter SDK Update: exportSyncFdForQSRILocked and sendCancelIfRunning Messages
There is ticket for this here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/160442
But in the meantime a temporary solution would be to add --no-enable-impeller to your run command.
Ex: flutter run --no-enable-impeller
Hope that helps.

How did you even know I am using flutter :')

Actually I don't. But this issue seems related to the flutter impeler engine.
